# Why is my custom loss (categorical cross-entropy) not working?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am working on some kind of framework for myself built on top of Tensorflow and Keras. As a start, I wrote just the core of the framework and implemented a first toy example. This toy example is just a classic feed forward network solivng XOR.

It's probably not necessary to explain everything around it but I implemented the loss function like this:

```py
class MeanSquaredError(Modality):

    def loss(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=y_pred.dtype)
        loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)(y_true, y_pred)
        return tf.reduce_sum(loss) / self.model_hparams.model.batch_size
```

This will be used in the actual model class like this:

```py
class Model(keras.Model):

    def loss(self, y_true, y_pred, weights=None):
        target_modality = self.modalities['targets'](self.problem.hparams, self.hparams)
        return target_modality.loss(y_true, y_pred)
```

Now, when it comes to training, I can train the model like this:

```py
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss=model.loss,  # Simply setting 'mse' works as well here
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

*or* I can just set `loss=mse`. Both cases work as expected without any problems.

However, I have another `Modality` class which I am using for sequence-to-sequence (e.g. translation) tasks. It looks like this:

```py
class CategoricalCrossentropy(Modality):
    """Simple SymbolModality with one hot as embeddings."""

    def loss(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        labels = tf.reshape(y_true, shape=(tf.shape(y_true)[0], tf.reduce_prod(tf.shape(y_true)[1:])))
        y_pred = tf.reshape(y_pred, shape=(tf.shape(y_pred)[0], tf.reduce_prod(tf.shape(y_pred)[1:])))
        loss = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE, from_logits=True)(labels, y_pred)
        return tf.reduce_mean(loss) / self.model_hparams.model.batch_size
```

What this does is just reshaping the `y_true` and `y_pred` tensors `[batch_size, seq_len, embedding_size]` to `[seq_len * batch_size, embedding_size]` - effectively stacking all examples. From this, the categorical cross-entropy is calculated and normalized.

Now, the model I am using is a very simple LSTM - this isn't important though. As I am training the model like this:

```py
model.compile(
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(0.001),
    loss='categorical_crossentropy',  # <-- Setting the loss via string argument (works)
    metrics=['accuracy']
)
```

The model does learn the task as expected. However, if I use the `CategoricalCrossentropy`-modality from above, setting `loss=model.loss`, the model does not converge at all. The loss oscillates randomly but does not converge.

And *this* is where I am scrathing my head. Since the simple XOR-examples works, both ways, and since setting `categorical_crossentropy` works as well, I do not quite see why using said modality doesn't work.

Am I doing something obviously wrong?

I am sorry that I cannot provide a small example here but this not possible since the framework already consists of some lines of code. Empirically speaking, everything *should* work.

Any ideas how I could track down the issue or what might be causing this?

Comment: I'm not sure you should use `model.loss`, if this is a property used by Keras, it will put a compiled function there, not a Python function.

Comment: @DanielMöller Oh, I didn't know that. I was planning to change the API anyway but now I know that I really should do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating a tuple of tensors for shape. That might not work.

Why not just this?

```
labels = tf.keras.backend.batch_flatten(y_true)
y_pred = tf.keras.backend.batch_flatten(y_pred)
```

The standard `'categorical_crossentropy'` loss does not perform any kind of flattening, and it considers as classes **the last axis**.

Are you sure you want to flatten your data? If you flatten, you will multiply the number of classes by the number of steps, this doesn't seem to make much sense.

Also, the standard `'categorical_crossentropy'` loss uses `from_logits=False`!

The standard loss expects outputs from a `"softmax"` activation, while `from_logits=True` expects outputs **without** that activation.

Comment: Hi! So .. My first mitake was definitely setting `from_logits=True`. This is wrong and should be set to `False`. Thank you for pointing this out. However, it's weird, I think `tf.keras.backend.batch_flatten(y_true)` should be equivalent to my `reshape()` .. but .. as I am starting the training, `val_loss` never improves when I am using `batch_flatten()`. This is very weird because it should be equivalent to what I am already doing.

Comment: Are you really sure you need to flatten your data? That doesn't make sense if a `'categorical_crossentropy'` works.

Comment: If I got that right, it expects a "list of one-hot encoded vectors", right? In my case this reshape should result in `[nb_words, vocab_size]` where `nb_words` is the number of one hot encoded vectors in total. This should result in a vector of errors. From this error I take the mean and normalize it with `batch_size`. Am I getting this wrong?

Comment: No, it returns `[batch_size, nb_words * vocab_size]` if you're calling `nb_words = length` and `vocab_size = output_classes`.

Comment: You're right - I thought I was doing the right thing but the implementation is wrong. However, in that case I need to `tf.transpose(tf.keras.backend.batch_flatten(tf.transpose(y_true)))` - now I have `[nb_words, vocab_size]`. Or, the corrected version when using `reshape()` would be `shape=(tf.reduce_prod(tf.shape(y_true)[:2]), tf.shape(y_true)[2])`. However, it's probably nicer to use `batch_flatten()`.

Comment: No, with that you're doing `[nb_words * vocab_size, batch_size]`.

Comment: Hm, I just debugged into it. In comes a tensor `y_true` taking the form `[400, 100, 5032]`.  `tf.keras.backend.batch_flatten(y_true)` gives `[400, 503200]` and `tf.transpose(tf.keras.backend.batch_flatten(tf.transpose(y_true)))` results in `[40000, 5032]` where `5032` is the vocab size of my targets. That make sense, looking at the [docs example](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/batch_flatten).

Comment: What is your target data shape? You should not transpose anything, your're disrupting the model's output.

Comment: If you have 400 input samples you should end with 400 output samples, no more, no less. If your target data has steps, you should not touch your data, no flatten, no transpose, nothing. If your target data does not have steps, you should remove the `return_sequences=True` in your last recurrent layer, or use a global pooling before the last dense layers.

Comment: Since the model is a translation model it outputs a sequence for each sample. Because of the one-hot encoding and the fact that the input is an entire batch, the tensors are three-dimensional (`y_true` and `y_pred`). Now, since the categorical cross-entropy function expects `[batch_size, vocab_size]` I have no other choice than reshaping my batch into this form. But this should be fine, shouldn't it? After all, I want to measure how many times the model predicted the correct word in that entire batch. `loss = categorical_crossentropy(true_words, predicted_words)`

Comment: The crossentropy expects `(batch_size, sentence_length, classes)`. You should not change it.

Comment: It seems that this is equivalent - both seems to work: https://gist.github.com/stefan-falk/8c27aec95767988d702783ef2fda79a1 The only thing to consider is that we have to transpose the data when using `batch_flatten()`.